# Divide 4 column to 2 column with Bulma CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

I have this code -

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column">column 1</div>
    <div class="column">column 2</div>
    <div class="column">column 3</div>
    <div class="column">column 4</div>
</div>
```

I want to make like this with Bulma css -
https://codepen.io/hashem/pen/ausJL

If I resize ( mobile version ) , those columns break in to 2 columns , instead 4 .

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/J15jLg That means 4 rows because it was already behaving like the way you wanted in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your question:

```
 <div class="columns is-mobile is-multiline">
  <div class="column is-half-mobile">column 1</div>
  <div class="column is-half-mobile">column 2</div>
  <div class="column is-half-mobile">column 3</div>
  <div class="column is-half-mobile">column 4</div>
</div>
```

If you want to fit in as many columns as possible and have them wrap when the screen size gets smaller use this:

```
<div class="columns is-mobile is-multiline">
  <div class="column">column 1</div>
  <div class="column">column 2</div>
  <div class="column">column 3</div>
  <div class="column">column 4</div>
  <div class="column">column 5</div>
  <div class="column">column 6</div>
  <div class="column">column 7</div>
  <div class="column">column 8</div>
  <div class="column">column 9</div>
  <div class="column">column 10</div>
</div>
```

Check these links for more information about what you're trying to do.
https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/responsiveness/

https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/